# Why /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/ and /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$/ accepts empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, nuxt.js

I am writing Nuxt web application and i encountered some strange thing.

```
export default {
    name: 'post',
    validate({ params }) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/.test(params.postname)
    }
}
```

This accepts "empty string", even it shouldn't. If it do not accept empty string, 404 error page should show up but it doesn't.

```
export default {
    name: 'post',
    validate({ params }) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$/.test(params.postname)
    }
}
```

This does as well. As far as i know, `+` and `{1,}` are identical. Why `+` and `{1,}` accepts empty string?

Comment: `Why + accepts empty string?` It shouldn't. Are you quite sure you're testing the proper string? Try `console.log`ging as well. Also note that alphabetical + digits + underscore simplifies to `\w` - no need for a character set at all

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/.test("") = false

Comment: This is full code

 <template>
  <div>
   test: "{{ this.$route.params.postname }}"
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 export default {
  name: 'post',
  validate({ params }) {
   return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$/.test(params.postname)
  }
 }
 </script>

browser shows me `test: ""` when i try to access `https://localhost:3000/posts/`

Comment: Like I said, try `console.log`ging inside `validate`, `+` should not accept the empty string, perhaps the function isn't running, or its return value isn't being used, but the test on an empty string *will* evaluate to `false` unless there's a bug in the engine, which is unlikely

Comment: Yea, it returns `true`.

Comment: I don't see any problem with regex.try to print params and check it's value once

Comment: `console.log(params.postname)` prints `undefined`. Does `undefined` matches any regex?

Comment: It gets stringified to 'undefined', which matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test()` method returns `true` if the string is undefined. So use:

```
return params.postname !== undefined && /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/.test(params.postname);
```